# Array is printing each letter of a word on separate line, how to fix?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on an assignment for school and the objective is to have the user input n amount of lines and then print them in reverse.

For example:

```
"Please enter number of lines: "
3
"Please enter the lines: "
Hi
Hey
Howdy
```

Desired Output:

```
Howdy
Hey
Hi
```

My output:

```
H
o
w
d
y
H
e
y
H
i
```

I'm not sure what's wrong and I'd really like some help, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseOrder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of lines: ");
    int numberOfLines = kb.nextInt() + 1;

    String inputLines[] = new String[numberOfLines];
    System.out.println("Please enter the lines: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        inputLines[i] = kb.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Lines in reverse: ");

    for (int i = numberOfLines - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= inputLines[i].length() - 1; j++) {
            System.out.println(inputLines[i].charAt(j));
        }
    }
    kb.close();
}
```

Comment: The code is not indented. That makes it much harder to reason about it. Fix that.

Comment: `println(char)` prints the character AND a new line. Have you tried `print` instead?

Comment: Why are you using a second for loop and printing each character? Just skip the second for loop and print `inputLines[i]`.

Comment: Did your teacher explain the difference between `System.out.println` and `System.out.print`?  And were you paying attention at the time?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing each character with an end of line character by calling println() with your current two for loops. This is one step too many.

Since you already have the entire string, you can simply print the strings in reverse order like so using the println() function

```
for(int i = numberOfLines - 1 ; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.println(inputLines[i]);         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kody

I'm not sure what you have to do in your code but:

If you need just print each line in a reverse order, you can do this:

```
System.out.println("Lines in reverse: ");

for (int i = numberOfLines - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(inputLines[i]);
}
```

The method **println** will create a new line for you.